# SSH tunnel over 2 servers

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I used the following command to create a tunnel from my system to server1 and from server1 to server2 to have a tunnel from my system to server2

`ssh -t -t -L4450:localhost:5590 user1@server1 'ssh -L 5590:localhost:2000  user@server2'`

But I get the following messages when I try to browse the web in my browser:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Is there anything wrong with the command?

EDIT:

My goal is to access internet via  server2(SOCKS Proxy). Because of some limits, I have to use a interface server(server1) to create a tunnel to server2.

Comment: One thing that could be wrong is that `-L` isn't the option normally used when one wants to "browse the web" over SSH, it is for establishing tunnels to a single explicit destination. What kind of program do you have running on `server2` on port 2000?

Comment: @grawity I find this command by searching in google. I changed 2000 to 80. With 80, it doesn't show the message anymore, but I still cant browse the web. Firefox shows "Connecting to example.com" and then says "Unable to connect"

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in your post -- for example, what were you trying to achieve in the first place? Browse the entire web via 'server2', or to access a single specific service?

Comment: @grawity I edited the post

Comment: Does server2 already have a SOCKS proxy running, or are you trying to create one using the tunnel?

Comment: @grawity I'm trying to create one using the tunnel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1946/discussion-between-hnik-and-grawity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the command:

```
ssh -t -L4450:localhost:5590 user1@server1 ssh -t -D5590 user@server2
```

The first ssh does a straight portforward of 4450 to server1, sending packets to its port 5590.  The second establishes a connection to server2 with a dynamic portforward (socks proxy) listening on server1 port 5590.

So packets from you going to your localhost:4450 will get forwarded to server1 5590, which is the dynamic port forward sent to server2 and out to the internet from the server2 IP.

Comment: Thanks. but Firefox says: The proxy server is refusing connections. Why?

Comment: maybe related: debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 4450.

Comment: Can you do `netstat -an | grep 4450` on the origin, and `netstat -an | grep 5590` on server1?

Comment: Yes. both have results

Comment: Now it works. I don't know why it didn't work before. Thanks